# Are there any equivalent of JMock in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, jmock

Are there any equivalent of JMock in Flex? There are FlexMock libraries, but they are for Python and Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several.  My favorite is Mockito, but you can take your pick:

- [Mockito](https://bitbucket.org/loomis/mockito-flex/wiki/Home)
- [Mockolate](http://mockolate.org/)
- [asMock](http://asmock.sourceforge.net/)